# What are the courses and majors available at Monsters University?

Tags: pixar, monsters-inc, monsters-university

Before a monster can work at Monsters Inc. they need to get a degree from Monsters University.

But I don't recall a list of what degrees, courses and majors are available.

Is there a complete course list?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The official [Monsters University website](https://web.archive.org/web/20150620/http://monstersuniversity.com/edu/academics.html) offers an insight into the various departments offering "*22 majors and 34 minors*" with an emphasis on Scaring and Engineering.

[image]

Specific courses mentioned include the practical (Canister Design, Door Design, Scaring, [Computer Sciences](https://web.archive.org/web/20150620/http://monstersuniversity.com/edu/students_don.html)) through to the more liberal (Acting, Directing, [New Age Philosophy](https://web.archive.org/web/20150620/http://monstersuniversity.com/edu/students_art.html),  [Dance & English](https://web.archive.org/web/20150620/http://monstersuniversity.com/edu/students_terri_terry.html)):

> Our undergraduates pursue bachelor's degrees ranging from **Canister
>   Design** to **Cognitive Neuroscience**. Our graduates have gone on to
>   shape our world in the fields of Power, Science, and Literature. And
>   while the awards, patents, and accolades help to reinforce our goals,
>   it is the pure impulse of intellectual desire that drives us.
>
> Our interdisciplinary opportunities in **molecular pharmacology** and
>   **physiology**, and our master's program in **acting** and **directing** through the MU Repertory Consortium all have helped establish MU as one of the most diverse academic environments in the
>   world.
>
> I remember one particular student, freshly admitted into the Semantics
>   department, who would gnash his mandibles wildly and swing his
>   enormously spiked tail at the first provocation or challenge, no
>   matter how insignificant. Little could be done to temper his behavior,
>   and we all thought he would not last long under the rigors of MU's
>   difficult **Semantics program**. But years later, I was pleased to see him
>   graduate and even more pleased when he approached me, a bit
>   sheepishly, after graduation and told me this:
>
> *"There is a difference between being a Monster, and behaving
>   monstrously.”*

Comment: That is an amazing website, thanks for finding it!